# Proxy forwarding my request to another user

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, proxy

we are running a web application into our tomcat server. like user1 and user2 registered with our server. user1 browsing our website, when user1 clicks a few links it is forwarding to correct URL but showing user2 credentials. we think intermediate proxy server between browser and our webserver proxy the request by registered user2. why it is happening? is it possible to block this proxying?

I do not have access to the internal proxy server. our web server based on tomcat apache with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your proxy server caches more aggressively than it should. As you don't state the software that you're using, check for the followings:

- What's the cache configuration for the proxy? I've seen proxies configured to explicitly ignore instructions by the appserver, and this naturally fails
- What cache-headers does tomcat generate for your pages? They should state that the page-level (HTML) responses are typically private and must not be cached, but typically are public, cacheable for js, css, images etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache has quite a few links that will help you understand more of the different caching options. If you need more specific input, please state the exact setup that you're using in your question.

*Edit*, Carrying the discussion from the comments back into the answer: It looks like you're suffering from a proxy that's not under your control - As I say in one comment, **https** might be your friend here: As soon as you encrypt the whole traffic (at least starting upon login) no proxy (*) will be able to read what's being passed through it. Using https for logged in content is a good idea anyway.

(*) No proxy? Well, there's a class of proxies that's still able to peek into your traffic (companies might install that in intranets, decode and reencode everything) but that's not your regular 3g provider.

Comment: we do not have access of the proxy server. it is 3g operator's proxy server.

Comment: actually when anyone visit through mobile phone via 3g then it is happening

Comment: we can use no-cache which will increase page loading time at client side. another thing we can restrict website access through proxy server but it is not feasible.

Comment: Well, no-cache is necessary for pages (that can't be cached), just not for other resources (like images, css, js typically etc.). After all you *want* personalized content not to be cached. Of course you could also go with https if the upstream proxy does not behave nice, bot somehow you sound like this would not be a preferred option for you.

Comment: we can not restrict caching . we have tried almost many thing like used random id in each dynamic url of our website, used no-cache, private but it is not helping us. :(